# No EJB found with interface of type 'CommonService' for binding BaseEntityServiceBean/commonService

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jboss, annotations, ejb

I have a common service interface:

```
@Local
public interface CommonService {

    public <T> T create(T entity) throws CreateException;
    public <T> T update(T entity) throws UpdateException;
    public <T> void delete(T entity) throws DeleteException;

    ...
}
```

`CommonService` implementation:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public class CommonServiceBean implements CommonService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="CLD_SV_JPA")
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public <T> T create(T entity) throws CreateException {
        this.em.persist(entity);
        this.em.flush();
        this.em.refresh(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T update(T entity) throws UpdateException {
        entity = this.em.merge(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void delete(T entity) throws DeleteException {
        Object reference = this.em.getReference(entity.getClass(), entity);
        this.em.remove(reference);
    }

    ...
}
```

There's the interface for all entity services (basically just an interface adding generics etc.):

```
public interface EntityService<K, T extends Entity<K>> {

    public T persist(T entity) throws CreateException, UpdateException;
    public T create(T entity) throws CreateException;
    public T update(T entity) throws UpdateException;
    public void delete(T entity) throws DeleteException;

    ...
}
```

Now I inject the `CommonService` bean into an abstract base class with `@EJB` that is the basis for all concrete service beans:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class BaseEntityServiceBean<K, T extends Entity<K>> implements EntityService<K, T> {

    // also tried protected without getter and setter, same problem        
    @EJB
    private CommonService commonService;

    public CommonService getCommonService() {
        return this.commonService;
    }

    public void setCommonService(CommonService commonService) {
//      this.commonService = commonService;
    }

    @Override
    public T create(T entity) throws CreateException {
        return this.commonService.create(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T entity) throws UpdateException {
        return this.commonService.update(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T entity) throws DeleteException {
        this.commonService.delete(entity);
    }

    ...
}
```

A concrete service bean is:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors({LoggingInterceptor.class, ExceptionInterceptor.class})
public class BarwertberechnungVerwaltungBean extends BaseEntityServiceBean<Integer, Barwertberechnung> implements BarwertberechnungVerwaltung {

    @Override
    public List<Barwertberechnung> findBarwertberechnungen(Integer partnerId, List<Integer> barwertberechnungArtIds) {
        ... // load stuff
    }
}
```

When deploying this to **JBoss AS 7** I get the exception

```
18:52:00,136 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."CLD-EAR.ear"."CLD-EJB3.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."CLD-EAR.ear"."CLD-EJB3.jar".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "CLD-EJB3.jar" of deployment "CLD-EAR.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011058: Failed to install component BarwertberechnungVerwaltungBean
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type 'de.bla.cld.service.CommonService' for binding de.bla.cld.service.BaseEntityServiceBean/commonService
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.processBindings(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:245)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.access$000(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor$1.handle(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:199)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deployComponent(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ComponentInstallProcessor.deploy(ComponentInstallProcessor.java:93)
    ... 6 more
```

Obviously the container cannot find the common service to be injected into the abstract base class `BaseEntityServiceBean`:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type 'de.bla.cld.service.CommonService' for binding de.bla.cld.service.BaseEntityServiceBean/commonService
```

What's wrong with my annotations? I see nothing... How do I fix this?

Comment: The EJB Client should use @EJB to inject the EJB interface not the EJB class itself.
The no-interface EJB can be injected, but only if the EJB does not implement an EJB interface.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. Hmmm. "The EJB Client should use @EJB to inject the EJB interface not the EJB class itself.": isn't this what I am doing via `@EJB private CommonService commonService;` where `CommonServiceBean` is its implementation?

Comment: Could the EAR deployment have to do with this? We have 3 EARs that we deploy for the application...